# Looking for ajax multi-upload solution using struts2

Tags: ajax, struts2

Our team is looking to support multiple concurrent uploads in struts2 (i.e. "ajaxy", gmail-style file uploads, with progress bars, that
begin immediately instead of when the user submits the form).

We are wondering if there are any tips or best practices for
implementing this feature.  For example, does struts require any
special handling for XHR multipart requests?  Also, is it appropriate
to use the FileUploadInterceptor for this sort of thing, or is it
better to roll our own?

We've briefly looked at [ajax-file-upload-struts2](http://code.google.com/p/ajax-file-upload-struts2/)
 but it looks as
though that project is either abandoned or incomplete (if that's wrong
please let me know).

As for the *client* side,  we've looked at swfupload, plupload, and
uploadify.  They seem to have their various strengths/weaknesses but
if anyone has a found a solution that they prefer we'd love to hear
it.

Comment: If you have found any solutions please share

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 already provides multiple file uploads functionality and its a good one in its own since its doing all the underlying work for you.i believe doing yourself means again doing the same work.
you can have look at current implementation of multiple file upload implementation and can tweak it as per your requirements
here is official document for the multiple file upload using struts2

[Multiple File Uploads](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-UploadingMultipleFiles)

Comment: Thanks Umesh.  I know that struts2 has support for multi-file uploads, but I'm looking for an "ajax-style" solution. One that begins uploading before the rest of the form has been submitted and, preferebly, one that provides a progress indicator.  Know of anything like that?

Comment: Hi NobodyMan.. did you find any solution... for the progress bar indicator for sturts 2 file upload... ? Kindly let me know if you have found any solution... i am searching the same :)